# How can I use Vite to build my Vue 3 plugin so that it's usable without a build process

Tags: vue.js, vite

I've set up a simple Vue plugin demo, it is being built with Vite: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/martinkz/simple-plugin/main?file=%2Fvite.config.js

I tried to build it as a library so that it can be included as a script tag and be used without a build process, but I'm not sure how to configure Vite to do this.

Here is a codepen that tries to use the resulting simple-demo-component.umd.js, but it doesn't seem to be built for that use case: https://codepen.io/Martin_Kz/pen/yLqrGmB

The end goal is for this component/plugin to be usable like this:

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Plugin test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <simple-demo-component />
    </div>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@latest"></script>
    <script src="https://grand-druid-f4a2ae.netlify.app/simple-demo-component.iife.js"></script>

    <script>
      const { createApp } = Vue;

      const app = createApp();
      app.use(SimpleDemoComponent);
      app.mount("#app");
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**Edit: This now works. I've updated the codesandbox, you can see it working in the Codepen demo.**

Comment: The question lacks https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , it will become useless for other readers if (or more precisely, when) these links become unavailable. Consider posting relevant code. The problem seems to be solely caused by the fact that you load a script from GH

Comment: Thanks, where else can I host a demo? I simplified it a little bit (removed the css file and eslint/prettier). It's already pretty close to a minimal demo, it needs the Vue plugin boilerplate and build config, as the entire point is building a minimal plugin. 

I've updated the script url, it loads correctly now, but the issue was there even locally, not just on codepen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `build.lib.format` or `build.lib.formats` option of vitejs reference: https://vitejs.dev/config/build-options.html#build-lib

```js
...
build: {
libs: {
entry: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/SimpleTestPlugin/index.js'),
name: 'SimpleDemoComponent',
// the proper extensions will be added
fileName: 'simple-demo-component',
formats: ['es', 'umd', 'iife'],
},

...
```

you seem to be new to these formats i will explain 4 supported formats vite

- `es`: compile to standard module
- `umd`: compile to javascript file in `self` and classic isolation (what you want)
- `iife`: same as `umd` but use `var` (`umd` will support other module import standards like commonjs but this one does not)
- `cjs`: compile to standard module commonjs

More: https://rollupjs.org/configuration-options/#output-format